# How to check if hour is on the next day php Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get data from database, and `if the created is today but the work_hour_end is on the next day, it will skip/ignore the data`.

The data is like this:

```
id  |  work_hour_start  |  work_hour_end
1   |  11:00:00         |  15:00:00
2   |  21:00:00         |  03:00:00  // work hour end on the next day, end of the day is 23:59
```

I've trying like code bellow, but still not working. Because there's no date in the `work_hour_end`.

```
 $attendance_in = Attendance::where('employee_id', $id)
                ->whereDate('work_hour_end', Carbon::today())
                ->whereDate('created', Carbon::today())
                ->first();
```

Comment: are you storing the whole timestamp or just the HH:MM:SS ?

Comment: @Jhecht for work_hour_start & end I'm just stroring the HH:MM:SS

Comment: Isn't it as simple as checking if `work_hour_end < work_hour_start`?

Comment: @kpie I want to ignore the data if it was created today but the work_hour_end is on the next day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we can assume `work_end_time` will always be greater than `work_start_time` if the event is on the same day. If `work_end_time` is smaller or equal to `work_start_time` we can assume the event will be in the next day. So, to determine this we will have to compare `work_end_time and work_start_time` column of same db row to get exact result.

```
$attendance_in = Attendance::where('employee_id', $id)
                ->whereColumn('work_hour_start','>=','work_hour_end')
                ->whereDate('created', Carbon::today())
                ->first();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `whereTime` method may be used to compare a column's value against a specific time:

```php
$attendance_in = Attendance::where('employee_id', $id)
               ->whereTime('work_hour_end', '<', '23:59')
               ->whereDate('created', Carbon::today())
               ->first();
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still get the data with work_hour_end on the next day

Comment: If you get data for the next day then there is no `created` column with today's date.

Comment: I want to ignore the data if it was created today but the work_hour_end is on the next day

Comment: In your question you said that you want to ignore the next day's data. You need to clarify your question then.

Comment: I've updated the question, sorry

Comment: And how do you know that `work_hour_end` is tomorrow? If it is an hour you can't make a condition like `28:59:32` a day doesn't have 28 hours, so you need an end date as well.

Comment: So it is not possible if only using HH:MM:SS?

Comment: No, it is best to convert your time column into a timestamp column.